# Can my husband board his flight 1 day before visa start date IF he lands in the UK on the start date?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, airlines, spouses

My Husbands Visa is Valid from the 30th Sept (Sunday) I'm trying to find out if he can board a flight on the 29th to land on the 30th or if he must board the flight on the 30th when the visa is already valid? I have contacted British Airways (who he's flying with) and all they stated was 'It should be fine but you must contact the UK Goverment'

Does anybody know who I should contact to get it in writing? I can't seem to find an e-mail address for general visa flight inquires. Has anyone done this before and was it okay?

Thank you for any help anyone can give me! It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Many similar questions on here. Ultimately the check in agents call the shots. No point contacting the government, the power to deny boarding lies with check in agent regardless of what note from the government you carry.

Comment: This surely happens all the time. For example, almost all flights from the USA to Europe are overnight. As @MusoniusRufus says, it's up to the airline whether or not you can get on the plane, and the airline says its OK.

Comment: @Fern Mooki I agree with David Richerby, this must happen all the time, and my partner has certainly done this in the past. One caveat around expected arrival time - ensure there’s some leeway in case the flight lands exceptionally early.